# Hi, does anyone know if the FDA has released ANDA submission dates?

Tags: data-request, releasing-data

I know the ANDA sometimes will comment on changes in ANDA review time, however the Orange book only provides the approval date and not the submission date.

Does anyone know either where the submission data has been released in the past, or if there's a specific office that we should be in contact with for this data?